# how to find best SVM predictive model when we do not have the y_test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I got the dataset to find the best machine learning model using SVM. But I only have x_train,y_train, and x_test datasets. I don't have the y_test dataset. I have to submit my answer to get the accuracy score.

How can I find the best SVM model?

About the problem: There are 4 types of vehicles that I need to identify using SVM model.X_train and x_test contains 18 numerical features and using that dataset I want to find the best SVM model.

Comment: Split your `X_train` and `y_train` further into train and validation sets.

Comment: This might be better on another stach exchange site, since you don't seem to be asking about code. However, try to split the x and y values you have into training and test data? try crossvalidation? This is like real life - you have some data to build a model.  How can you be confident it will work on unseen data?

Comment: Better use [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or e.g. following link to search for [SVM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svm).